# Entity Framework Linq IntelliSense Problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2019

I have problem with Visual Studio 2019 and Entity Framework. When I apply `Join` method, IntelliSense gave me suggestions for first entity, but on a second I get situation shown in the below screenshot.

Funny thing is that the code works if I type names of entity files correctly. Thanks

[image]

Comment: What exactly is you are asking? Why it is not working? Or how to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried using linq query syntax instead as a workaround? I usually find it a lot more readable for joins

Comment: @JonasHøgh I can't use it because company guidelines for coding is that we must all use same syntax.

Comment: @krazors This is definitely Intellisense specific problem. Until it gets resolved, you have to type the property manually and the compiler will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it is not working?**

Currently is reported an issue that is under investigation(Jan 10th, 2020).

[Reported issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/734638/intellisense-not-working-properly-witch-join-of-li.html)

**How to make it work?**

You might want to declare generic arguments explicitly.

```
dbContext.people.Join<TInner, TOuter, TKey, TResult>(...)
```

Comment: Just bad choice of words - "Funny thing is that the code works if I type names of entity files correctly.", it works that way, as you said. Thanks anyway :)